# Which are the positive integers for which the number $n^2 + 5n +6$ is a perfect square?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

This is a problem from this year´s local Olympiad exam from Catalunya (2022/2023).

I have tried solving this problem without success. The only useful thing I came up with is that it might be solved by inequalities as its intervals are positive integers and not real numbers. I think I must have forgotten some important concepts that I would be grateful if you could tell me which.

I wish you could help me solve this problem. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Can you factors the quadratic in $n$?

Comment: Similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/830009/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128670/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2272982/42969

Comment: You mean in (n+2)(n+3)?

Comment: or $ (n+2)^2 < n^2 + 5n + 6 < (n+3)^2$  which would still work   for altered polynomial, $ (n+2)^2 < n^2 + 5n + 7 < (n+3)^2$   where this one does not factor

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Is possible to do that Will? Is it any formula?

Comment: $N=(n+2)(n+3)$ so $n+2=ax^2,\space\space n+3=by^2$ with $ab=$ square. It seems that solving the equation in $n$ is easier and inmediate. because the discriminant equal to $1$.

Comment: Hi Martin. The problem is only the title, it does not have extra information. The point that you are trying to emphasize is that I have to put the question again in the body?

Comment: Hi @Piquito. Thanks for your help. But there is one understand, how did you know that n+2=ax2,  n+3=by2 ??

Comment: I am quite a beginer and I am trying to learn. Sorry if the question is elementary.

Comment: Alternate approach: $$n^2 + 5n + 6 = k^2 \implies 4n^2 + 20n + 24 = 4\left(k^2\right) \implies $$ $$(2n+5)^2 - 1 = (2k)^2 \implies $$ $$[(2n+5) - 2k)] \times [(2n+5) + 2k] = 1.$$

Comment: Hi @Still_learning.  I saw that $n+2$ and $n+3$ are consecutive but anyway my first assertion was deficient and the second one it would be preferable. In any time it was been proved that the product of consecutive integers is never a power.

Comment: Thanks! But what about 0 and 1? That product is a perfect square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no integer solutions because

$$(n+2)^2 = n^2+4n+4 \lt n^2+5n+6 < n^2 + 6n + 9 = (n+3)^2$$

and there are no other integers between $n+2$ and $n+3$.

Comment: How did you know that inequality? Is that a formula or something?

Comment: I am quite noob so sorry if the question is elementary

Comment: Just compare the terms. Technically, I'm assuming here that $n>0$ but otherwise the inequality should just switch around. All three have an $n^2$ term. Obviously $4<6<9$ and if $n>0$, then you also have $4n<5n<6n$

Comment: Oh. So what you basically this was putting a limit to (n+2)(n+3) , and the two closest ones are those??

Comment: You mean there are no positive integer solutions. $n\in\{-2, -3\}$ obviously work otherwise.

Comment: @Macavity, you are right but the problem is seeking for positive integers

Comment: Oh I was editing my answer to include the negative integers, only just realized why I originally ignored those...

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution: we solve over the integers.

$n^2 + 5n + 6 = (n + 2)(n + 3)$. Now $n + 2$ and $n + 3$ are comprime, so if their product is a square, both of these factors must also be squares (or both must be the negation of squares). The only squares 1 apart are $0$ and $1$, so we must have $n = -2$ or $n = -3$. These are the only solutions over the integers, and neither is positive.

Comment: I was thinking of positing an answer like this.  We could also have $n=-3$ (another non-positive solution)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Good catch. I’ve added that to my answer.